# Can't get self-signed certificate to work in my app but works with s_client

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am working with the example apps in the "Networking Security with OpenSSL" book and up until now have been able to get client/server examples 1,2,3 to work. But now I'm trying to connect to an in-house tool but I'm getting the error "error 18:self signed certificate". Despite this error when I run my app (essentially client3), when I use s_client with the very same credentials...it works.

I suspect that it has something to do with the ssl/tls api combination that I use in my 'client3' app.

Here's the command and output for s_client that connects to the in-house tool which works:

```
~/tls/client$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.99:16001 -CAfile ../_security/SipInspector/certificate.pem -key ../_security/client.pem
Enter pass phrase for ../_security/client.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = CA, ST = Ontario, L = Ottawa, O = SIP Inspector Ltd, OU   =     Development, CN = 192.168.1.99
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development/CN=192.168.1.99
   i:/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development/CN=192.168.1.99
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development/CN=192.168.1.99
issuer=/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development/CN=192.168.1.99
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2309 bytes and written 509 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID:       5755C781D91CF3177DF624EA3599EE430DAB4790F325FAD9378FEAE7731C4497
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: D149008E43E29D658D29418C9F770B3D6018B1D7CA2F493027B0AC7C3BA8E53B572B68C371153568B8988A1E5F351839
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1465239425
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Here's the command and output when I run my app that tries to connect to the same in-house tool which fails:

```
carl@ubuntu:~/tls/client$ ./client3 192.168.1.99
Enter PEM pass phrase:
connecting to 192.168.1.99:16001
 -Error with certificate at depth: 0
   issuer   = /C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development   /CN=192.168.1.99
   subject  = /C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=SIP Inspector Ltd/OU=Development/CN=192.168.1.99
   err 18:self signed certificate
 ** client3.c:94 Error connecting SSL object
139788992993088:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:s3_clnt.c:1180:
carl@ubuntu:~/tls/client$
```

Here are the api's I call in the my app that utilize the same credentials used by the s_client command:

```
 SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());
 SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "../_security/SipInspector/certificate.pem", NULL)
 SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "../_security/client.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
 SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);
 SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
 SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
```

And also I used the openssl verify command to double check the certificate against itself (not sure if this really does anything).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("../_security/SipInspector/certificate.pem", NULL)` return?  Also, that's incorrect, as `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` [takes three arguments](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html).

Comment: Check if your client supports a cipher that's supported by the server - The OpenSSL client used ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA for example. Maybe you just forgot to call `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()` ?

Comment: Corrected arguments. Returns 1.

Comment: Tried OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms() with no luck. Confirmed that the server chooses a cipher from the list sent by the client.

Comment: Is there a way to bring out more debug from the app for this error?

Comment: @carlh: you can retrieve/print the actual error messages directly from openssl - Check [ERR_print_errors](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html) or [ERR_error_string](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_error_string.html), or similar functions referenced in these pages.

Comment: @jweyrich: actually my app uses ERR_print_errors_fp() to print to stderr. The error output can be seen above when I invoke ./client3. But the error message is too general. Need something more specific if possible.

Comment: @carlh: oh, I see now. I'd also suggest checking the return value of your calls to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file`. Are they failing?

Comment: @jweyrich: yes they are checked and they are not failing.

Comment: @carlh: I'm running out of options. Is your certificate password protected (PKCS#12)? If yes, you'll need to [setup a callback](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb.html) that provides it -

Comment: @jweyrich: certificate is not password protected. Private key is however but i enter the password for it at the command line for now.

Comment: @carlh: understood. I'm assuming you're using `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb` or `SSL_set_default_passwd_cb` then. Is that correct? If you could provide all the relevant pieces of code, it would be helpful.

Comment: @jweyrich: Again I enter the password at the command line for the Private Key file. See above. Here are the api's i'm using:

Comment: @carlh: But how you're informing the openssl context to use the password you typed? Your question doesn't show how. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @jweyrich: I don't inform openssl that it needs a password for the Private Key file because openssl can tell if the Private Key file is password protected when I run ./client3. See above. Note that openssl prompts me for password. Therefore I don't need the password function. You can see this in the second box above. **'Enter pass phrase for ../_security/client.pem:'**. Besides my question is not related to a password failure of the Private Key file. It's related to the certificate.

Comment: @carlh: alright. I'm out of options for now. If you could provide the relevant code you're using, we may give you more insights. For now, I don't know why the openssl client connects fine while your client app doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turned out to be the certificate check routine was checking against incorrect information in the received certificate.